# What is the meaning of this error "Error in if (any(B < 1)) stop("B too small")" while using tabplot package

Tags: r, ff

I found the tabplot package for visualizin a large data base. I ran it using the code below but I get this error on different data frames:

```
"Error in if (any(B < 1)) stop("B too small") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In bbatch(n, as.integer(BATCHBYTES/theobytes)) : NAs introduced by coercion"
```

Here is an example:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " birds    wolfs     snakes
                     3        9         7
                     3        8         4
                     1        2         8
                     1        2         3
                     1        8         3
                     6        1         2
                     6        7         1
                     6        1         5
                     5        9         7
                     3        8         7
                     4        2         7
                     1        2         3
                     7        6         3
                     6        1         1
                     6        3         9
                     6        1         1   ",header = TRUE)
install.packages("tabplot")
package ‘ff’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘bit’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fastmatch’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘ffbase’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tabplot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
library("tabplot", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
 tab <- tableplot(dat, plot = FALSE) ## The tabplot  command
Error in if (any(B < 1)) stop("B too small") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In bbatch(n, as.integer(BATCHBYTES/theobytes)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any Idea how to overcome this issue?

**UPDATE** - I used another computer and it works fine.Both computers are on  Windows 64-bit but on the computer that I got it to work the OS is Win7 pro and on the computer that has the error the OS is WIN SERVER 2013

Comment: I only get a warning (v. 1.1). What version of the package are you using?

Comment: At this point, I think we will need a reproducible example. Can anyone reconfirm the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a comment by [schuemie](https://github.com/edwindj/ffbase/issues/37#issuecomment-52470925), this error has to do with the amount of memory needed by `ffdfdlpy`, and can be fixed with a per-session run of

`options(ffmaxbytes = min(getOption("ffmaxbytes"),.Machine$integer.max * 12))`

will allow this to work.

I can confirm this works with `sessionInfo()`:

`R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1`

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the command `bbatch(n, as.integer(BATCHBYTES/theobytes))`. Whatever you are doing is causing `NA`s to be introduced when integers are expected. And `any(NA < 1)` gives `NA`. This has the effect that the `if()` command can't decide if your value is `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```
if ( NA ) stop("This is silly")
#  Error in if (NA) stop("This is silly") : 
#    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

My guess (and it's an utter guess at this stage without further testing) is to try adding `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your `read.table()` command.

Comment: Adding stringsAsFactors=FALSE  didn't help...All variables are of int type.

Comment: @mql4beginner `In bbatch(n, as.integer(BATCHBYTES/theobytes)) : NAs introduced by coercion` tells me that something, somewhere is not of `integer` or `numerical` type. I suggest looking at what exactly `BATCHBYTES` and `theobytes` are.

Comment: I read that BATCHBYTES  and theobytes  are related to the 'ffdfdply' package that is used by 'tabplot' package but I don't see how can I change them