# Removing rows in list (with ff)

Tags: r, subset, ff

I have a data set where I want to remove every row in which **Dataset$a**
does not have the value **"Right"**. **Dataset$a** is a list with three diffrent objects "**Right"**, **"Wrong1"** and **"Wrong2"**. I tried to do this by using the code:

```
Dataset$a <- subset.ffdf(Dataset, a == "Right")
```

But I get the error

```
Error in if (any(B < 1)) stop("B too small") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In bbatch(n, as.integer(BATCHBYTES/theobytes)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: `new_dataset <- Dataset[Dataset$a == "Right", ]`

Answer (score 0):

The warning that is returned has something do in working with a large data set.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027316/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-error-error-in-if-anyb-1-stopb-too-small)

Before doing your filter see if row `a` is a factor or character using:

```
str(Dataset$a)
```

If it is in character format, this should work

```
finalDf <- Dataset[Dataset$a != "Right", ]
```

Or you can use `dplyr` like so:

```
require(dplyr)

newData <- Dataset%>% dplyr::filter(a=="Right")
```