# R: error in tableplot: Error in if (by < 1) stop("'by' must be > 0")

Tags: r, plot

I'm a beginner in R and cannot understand what's the problem in that simple code:

```
install.packages("tabplot")
library("tabplot")
library("MASS")
Boston$chas <- factor(Boston$chas)
Boston$rad <- ordered(Boston$rad)
tableplot(Boston)
```

After running the function 'tableplot' I get this error message:

```
Error in if (by < 1) stop("'by' must be > 0") : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
`In addition: Warning message:
In chunk.default(from = 1L, to = 506L, by = c(double = 23058430092136940),  :NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

What is the problem? There're no missing values in the dataset. Could someone explain it, please?

Many thanks in advance
Daria

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error, even when running the standard `diamonds` example from the documentation. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027316/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-error-error-in-if-anyb-1-stopb-too-small) it could be a memory issue, so you could try the command there. It didn't help for me though, this feels like a bug.

Comment: I executed your code on my machine, and everything works fine (without errors, without warnings), yielding a nice plot.

Comment: hmm that's strange.. maybe something's wrong with my PC... but many thanks for your help